# How to Execute Block Of Code Only One Time (Once) inside For Each inside and While Loop in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create looping as below:

I have no clue as how to do this and it ended up my loop will execute preparation and execution for every the_num and every while loop

```
worker.py
def preparation(the_num):
    public datafram_e
    print ('This is preparation ' + str(the_num))
def execution(the_num):
    public datafram_e
    print ('This is execution ' + str(the_num)) 
def protocol(the_num):
    preparation(the_num)
    execution(the_num)  

manager.py
from worker import protocol
if__name__ == "__main__":
    while True:  
        numbers = 'Uno', 'Dos', 'Tres'
        for the_num in numbers:
           protocol(the_num)
```

What I want is to execute def preparation(the_num) only one time for every time while loop is started.

Output:

```
This is preparation Unos
This is execution Unos
This is preparation Dos
This is execution Dos 
This is preparation Tres
This is execution Tres
This is execution Unos
This is execution Dos 
This is execution Tres
This is execution Unos
```

and so on....

Thanking you in advance for any information you are able to provide

Comment: Why not just call `preparation` and `execution` separately? Prep outside your for-loop, exec inside.

Comment: The 'preparation' will generate dataframe that will be used in the 'execution'. Please advice how to make dataframe from prep available for use by 'exec'. Preps will generate: dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3 and dataframe4 (one time). And exec while loop will use this dataframes every minute (the dataframe is machine learning model),

Comment: "_Please advice how to make dataframe from prep available for use by 'exec'._" I would use a class to encapsulate your dataframe variables. But for simplicity, you _could_ also just set it as a global variable.